# Advanced Search Query with multiple INNER JOIN doesn't work as expected

Tags: mysql, inner-join

**Structure**

---

**members** id (auto, int), fullName (varchar), isReseller (enum), reseller_id (int), country_id, city_id, town_id, landLine, admin (enum)

**subscriptions** id (auto, int), transaction_id (int), magazine_id (int), cargo (varchar), startDate(date), endDate(date), active(enum), status (enum), reseller_id (int), member_id (int)

**transactions** id (auto, int), bankaccount_id (int), member_id (int), creator_admin_id(int), paymentDate (date)

**magazines** id (auto,int), name (varchar)

**bankaccounts** id (auto,int), name(varchar)

**Query**

---

```
SELECT 

s.id, s.cargo, s.startDate, s.endDate, s.active, s.status, 
mag.name as magazineName, 
b.name as bankName, t.id as transaction_id, 
m.fullName, m.id as member_id, 
mm.fullName as resellerName, mm.id as reseller_id 

FROM  asw_subscriptions as s 
INNER JOIN  asw_members as m ON m.id = s.member_id 
INNER JOIN  asw_transactions as t ON t.id = s.transaction_id 
INNER JOIN  asw_members as mm ON mm.id = t.member_id 
INNER JOIN  asw_magazines as mag ON mag.id = s.magazine_id 
INNER JOIN  asw_bankaccounts as b ON b.id = t.bankaccount_id 

WHERE 

m.fullName LIKE '%john%' AND 
m.country_id = '224' AND  
m.admin = '0'  AND 
m.reseller_id = '45677' AND 
s.magazine_id = '1' AND 
s.active = '1'  AND 
s.reseller_id = '45677' AND 
t.paymentDate BETWEEN '2011-10-01' AND '2011-10-29'  AND 
t.creator_admin_id = '45677' OR 
t.member_id = '45677' 

ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 25
```

**PROBLEM**

---

1. Resellers can place order for other members.
2. I keep resellers in the same database as members. isReseller value is 1.
3. When a member has reseller, reseller_id is greater than 0 (member id value of reseller).
4. When reseller places an order it also creates transaction record.

This query above displays every subscription order is done by reseller regardless to any search criteria for members and subscription status (if I search `active = '1'`, it still displays all).

Even if I will write John, it will display all orders of selected reseller.

It just like as if I made a query just for searching reseller's order with given payment dates (`t.paymentDate BETWEEN '2011-10-01' AND '2011-10-29'` ).

I don't know howelse to explain this situation. If I wasn't clear please let me know, I will try edit my question and be more specific.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unclear as to exactly what data you want back, but I think maybe you should join from the transactions into the members (just once) and then do some grouping to count orders (if that's what you're after).
Also note that AND is evaluated before OR - so the final OR statement stands against all the AND's evaluated together. Use parentheses () to group your OR/AND/BETWEEN statements correctly.

Comment: Wow, I totally forgot about it. This solved the problem. `(t.creator_admin_id = '45677' OR t.member_id = '45677')` thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your inner join:

```
INNER JOIN  asw_members as mm ON mm.id = t.member_id
```

already guarantees that t.member_id = mm.id so adding the exact same condition in the where clause in the OR statement guarantees you'll get the full set based on the joins alone. See above answer about parentheses.

If mm is the reseller and m is the member, I think you want the following:

```
INNER JOIN asw_members as mm ON (mm.id = t.member_id OR t.member_id = mm.id)
```

Then in your WHERE clause:

```
m.reseller_id = mm.id AND
s.reseller_id = mm.id AND
mm.id = '45677' AND
....<other filters>
```

Sometimes if you are going to join a table in twice, you might want to shorthand your resellers as r and your members as m. It makes it easier to remember who is who.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. I wanted to rest before checking it out again.  Unfortunately `INNER JOIN asw_members as mm ON (mm.id = t.member_id OR t.member_id = mm.id)` didn't do the trick :( I'm still getting all the orders of all reseller's members.